# Problem with WordPress admin bar with nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a WordPress site which I'm trying to switch from Apache to Nginx. I've got it working OK, except that the admin bar which appears across the top of each page when logged in is not styled and appears as just a standard HTML list (it's fine under Apache). Given that the rest of the site seems to be working OK, I'm a bit puzzled why a small part of the page should behave differently under nginx than Apache, and I'm hoping someone might be able to point me to something to look at. The page source is identical, so the issue must be down to the way it handles one or more of the resources on the page.

LATER: The problem can be expressed more simply than this. Served from Apache, 'wp-login.php' shows the login form correctly. Served from nginx, it shows it unstyled, as if it can't find the CSS (although no errors show up in the Chrome console). As mentioned earlier, actual source for the page is identical from the 2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

As ever, the answer turned out to be simple (and nothing to do with WordPress). The 'mime.types' file was missing from the nginx config, which meant that CSS wasn't being served as 'text/css' but as 'application/octet-stream'.